# How to create Asset Library (BaseTemplate = 851) in Sharepoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

Been searching through the internet for a couple of days to no avail but how do you create Asset Library with BaseTemplate = 851 in modern sites for **Sharepoint Online via the REST API V1.0 endpoint**? I am able to create Lists, Document libraries & Picture libraries with no issues but when I use **BaseTemplateId = 851** the REST endpoint is not accepting the payload.

```
data = JSON.stringify({
        "__metadata": {"type": "SP.List"},
        "AllowContentTypes": true,
        "BaseTemplate": 851,  
        "ContentTypesEnabled": true,
        "Description": "My list description",
        "Title": foldername
      
    })

headers.append("Authorization", bearer)
headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose")
headers.append("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose")
headers.append("X-RequestDigest", formDigestValue)
const options = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: headers,
    body: data
};

return fetch(folderPath + '/_api/web/lists', options)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => console.log(response))
```

BaseTemplate - 100, 101 & 109 are just working fine and I am able to create lists and document libraries. 851 is not working programmatically though I can create Assets Library manually ( I have activated Video and Rich Media Site Collection Features).

Any help here would be much appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, you can´t create an AssetLibrary with REST.

You can create it with PnP PowerShell.

```
New-PnPList -Title "Test Asset Library" -Url "Lists/TestAssetLibrary"  -Template AssetLibrary
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. We have a web-facing SPA with react which is also a PWA. It is not possible to run powershell on a client device. I see other apps like Team, Power Automate that can create asset libraries so I am wondering if there is a way to create AssetLIbraries on the fly with REST esp considering all other libraries and lists can be created. Also, I have seen C# code that does the same via CSOM. Can you suggest any other way of doing this via Javascript? Our App is not running within the Sharepoint context but a separate application on its own. Thank you